# 10th previous line from a match

Tags: text-processing, grep, head

How can I get the 10th previous line from a match? I think using grep with the option B and then piping it into head would work, but is there a simpler way to do this?

For example, if I had a text file like this

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
```

and if I chose the pattern to be "l", I'll get the 10th previous line, which is "b".

Answer (score 5):

The `grep`/`head` approach works perfectly fine.  Doubt there's a simpler way.  If multiple matches, only shows the first match.

```
$ grep -B 10 l x|head -1
b
$
```

GNU `awk` solution, using a circular buffer.  If multiple matches, shows each match.

```
$ awk '/^l$/{print a[NR%10]};{a[NR%10]=$0}' x
b
$
```